# Pandas: Include rows where column_x.min() and column_y between two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset containing rows of measurements (weight) in the following format:

`user_id`, `day_n`, `weight`

- `user_id` is the identifier of the user. There are multiple rows
  with the same `user_id`.
- `day_n` is the day number on which the measurement is done.
- `weight` is the weight in kg.

For removing outliers or incorrect data, I use a min and max value for both the `weight` and the `day_n` column.

For now, I plot all data into a [scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3426.png).

**My question:**

How can I only include users, which have their first measurement (`weight`) between two values (`min_weight` and `max_weight`)?

Considering the following example data and `min_weight` = 70 and `max_weight` = 75, `user_id` 1 should be included, but `user_id` 2 should not.

```
user_id, day_n, weight
1, 0, 72
1, 28, 70
1, 68, 69
2, 5, 76
2, 28, 80
2, 78, 78
```

**I tried:**

I tried to group by `user_id` and looked for the min() of `day_n`. I couldn't figure out how to check the `weight` in this row.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('../datasets/measurements_2019-12-31_2021-07-01.csv')

# Min and max weights
df = df[df['weight'] > 25]
df = df[df['weight'] < 300]

# Min and max days
df = df[df['day_n'] > -7]
df = df[df['day_n'] < 187]

# Only include rows with > 3 measurements
df = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)

# Scatter plot
plt.scatter(df['day_n'], df['weight'])

# Regression line
m, b = np.polyfit(df['day_n'], df['weight'], 1)
plt.plot(df['day_n'], m*df['day_n']+b,color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What you can do is to sort each group of user_id by day_n and then take the first value of this group `df.sort_values(['user_id', 'day_n']).groupby('user_id')['weight'].first()`. Then filter this with your min/max criteria. Those users you exclude then from your original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

sort then find the user id to keep:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'day_n': [0, 28, 68, 5, 28, 78],
                   'weight': [72, 70, 69, 76, 80, 78]})
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'day_n'])
keep_user = df.groupby('user_id')['weight'].first().between(70, 75)
df.loc[df['user_id'].isin(keep_user[keep_user].index)]
```

```
    user_id day_n   weight
0   1       0       72
1   1       28      70
2   1       68      69
```